# Record count and Filename from VSAM Source EBCDIC encoding in Informatica PowerCenter

Tags: mainframe, informatica-powercenter, ebcdic, vsam

I need to get the **filename** and then **count the number of records** in that VSAM source file in **Informatica PowerCenter 10**. I had already done similar thing with other flat files in which from the source instance I can get the file name by checking "CurrentlyProcessedFileName" option. Whereas for VSAM source, there is no option in there. 
Please see the below snaps for reference.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

UPDATE (ROW COUNT):

[image]

Comment: I dont think informatica provide any direct way to load file name for VSAM. You can use pre-session shell/batch script to store the loading file name into a file/db table and do a lookup into the mapping to fetch it. But this approach can be an issue if you process multiple files at a time.

Comment: Yes there are multple files. I can get the filename by making a separate source instance but unable to get he count of records.

Comment: If you are creating separate source instance, why not adding an aggregator to get count of rows? It will be a simple transformation - get any key column and create a new o/p port as COUNT(*).

Comment: Yes I tired to get the count in the same way (count(filename)), but due to VSAM source it does not give count for rows the file has. Whereas the same approach works for other flatfiles. It is the nature of file that is causing issue.

Comment: Just added an update in the main question to capture the row count for other files.. not working for this VSAM one.

Comment: i see the issue. Is it possible for you to use $PMSourceQualifierName@numAffectedRows session variable to capture affected rows from source? You may need to use it in session.

Comment: Hi, i do not know how to get the value for session parameters in a table or something. I am looking into, if you have a way then it will be nice to share with me.

Comment: You can use a post session SQL command to update any table[insert into table_name (workflow_name,source_rows_read) values ($PMWorkflowName,$PMSQ_Name@numAffectedRows ) 
]. You can also use post session success CMD task to write this value into a file[echo $PMSQ_Name@numAffectedRows > $PMSourceFileDir\$PMWorkflowName_stat.txt
]. But this will be total impacted rows. If you have 100 rows in 5 files, this parameter will return 100.